# Adding laravel CSRF token with form data

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

While uploading an image via wysiwyg editor I need to pass the Laravel CSRF token with the `FormData()`. But it seems like it fails or it does not add the csrf token using the `append()` method.

Here is my code:

```
  function uploadImage( image ) {
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append( "image", image );

    data.append( "csrfToken", Laravel.csrfToken ); // <- adding csrf token
    // Laravel.csrfToken will return the csrf token.

    console.log( data.entries() );
    $.ajax ({
      data: data,
      type: "POST",
      url: "/article/store/image",
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(url) {
        var image = IMAGE_PATH + url;
          $( '#editor' ).summernote( "insertImage", image );
        },
        error: function( data ) {
          console.log( data );
        }
    });
  }
```

[image]

Its not adding the laravel csrf token with the form data because still I am getting an error

> TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68

How to add the token with the form data?

Comment: What `Laravel.csrfToken` returns?

Comment: @SaumyaRastogi just the token string.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should add a field named - `_token`, instead of `csrfToken` like this:

```
data.append( "_token", Laravel.csrfToken ); // <- adding csrf token
```

This is what Laravel's helper method - [`csrf_field()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-csrf-field) does.

According to [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token), in case of Ajax calls - you could, for example, store the token in a HTML meta tag::

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

and then include in your ajax header like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   headers: {
       'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
   }
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

For ajax requests, I like to set it up once with $.ajaxSetup.

In my layout:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

In my app.js:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

This saves me having to remember to append the _token input to every request.

Answer (score 2):

while @Saumya already answered this question, I use headers to send CSRF tokens like so:

```
$.ajax ({
  data: data,
  type: "POST",
  headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': Laravel.csrfToken },
  url: "/article/store/image",
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function(url) {
    var image = IMAGE_PATH + url;
      $( '#editor' ).summernote( "insertImage", image );
    },
    error: function( data ) {
      console.log( data );
    }
});
```

If you are using ajax to send multiple requests throughout your application, you can set it up globally for every request at once:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': Laravel.csrfToken
}
});
```

Learn more [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token)